# Why Are No Duplicates Allowed An Attribute Of HashSet?

Tags: java, hashset

A well known feature of `HashSet` is that it doesn't allow duplicates. For example:

```
HashSet<Integer> h = new HashSet<>();
h.add(5);
h.add(5); // this time it won't allow it, because its a duplicate.
```

However, why is this the case? It seems useful to have a data-structure that adds in best case O(1) and searches in best case O(1), and it will still be useful if I had duplicates. Does the way that Java implements `HashSet` not allow it to have duplicates, or is it just a choice because of some reason?

Comment: A set, in theory, has only unique values. Think of a mathematical set: "*In mathematics, a set is a well-defined collection of **distinct** objects*".

Comment: Sets are defined as containing only unique elements in formal logic.

Comment: That's _the definition_ of a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is a well known attribute of [**`Set`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), the first line of the linked JavaDoc reads

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Thus [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (and all other correctly implemented `Set`(s)) do not allow duplicates.

Comment: Are there any hashing data structures that allow duplicates?

Comment: Look at *All Known Implementing Classes* in the [`Collection` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). Exactly what kind of data structure are you looking for?

Comment: @NishantChatterjeeKMS what kind of "set" it would be if it would allow for duplicates?

Comment: @itwasntme I mean is there something like a HashList? A list that uses hashing?

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head; such a `List` would not have sensible iteration semantics. **Why** do you want one? There is a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) which does not allow duplicates (because it is a `Set`), but does allow access from a key and also internally maintains a doubly-linked list.

Comment: There is [Guava's MultiSet](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html): "A collection that supports order-independent equality, like Set, but may have duplicate elements. A multiset is also sometimes called a bag."

Comment: @NishantChatterjeeKMS if you read about data structures, you'll understand that lists are implemented using pointers from one node to the next. Having a "hash" in this case makes no sense.

Comment: @NishantChatterjeeKMS Why would you want to hash duplicates? If anything, those "duplicates" should be seen as the same constant, if they are expected to never change. If you want instant access to a group of values (such as potential duplicates), you may be looking for a Multi-Set structure. Hashes rely on uniqueness.